# back button which should go back to same div/section/position in viewport on the previous page from where I redirected to current page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I want to make a back button on page B which redirects me to the previous page. For this I have used `onClick={() => navigate(-1)` react hook, but on after redirecting it is showing the page A(previous page) from the top.

I want to redirect to the same section from where I left before going to page B. (hope I am clear)

FYI: I have used `<ScrollToTop />` in App.tsx because I want to see every page from the top on redirection/refresh. If I don't use `<ScrollToTop />` then I am not able to get any page from the top.

Please let me know any solution for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share `<ScrollToTop />`

Comment: `export default function ScrollToTop() {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        document.documentElement.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        });
    }, [pathname]);

    return null;
}`

Answer (score 0):

After the button or link in Page A has been clicked, try running a function for saving the `window.pageYOffset` in a state variable managed outside the component, so it doesn't refresh on mounting. You can use React ContextAPI or Redux (Or prop drilling, which can take a while depending on how deep the component is, but is probably the simplest way if you don't have prior knowledge of the other stated). The `window.pageYOffset` holds the Y-Position of the window.

Assuminng the state variable is named `savedPosition` when you click the "Go Back button on Page B, you can use `window.onload = () => {window.scrollTo({top: savedPosition, left: 0})};`